# Producing several ARIMA forecasts at the same time. Can I store them in an array for future use?

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

```
arima_fcast[j] = forecast(arima_output, h=24)
plot(arima_fcast[j], main=paste("Forecast for ", j))
```

I want to create a record of the ARIMA forecasts I have produced in an array but when I plot the forecast I get the following message

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

Its not storing the actual forecast info in the array.  Is there something I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: You generally story R objects in a list and then reference the list items.  E.g. arima_list[[3]] would contain the arima forecast for the 3rd analysis.

Comment: Thanks.  Not sure why I didn't do that.